# Use a sql:query output as a variable in another query

Tags: sql, jsp

strugggling with what is probably fairly simple jsp code so any assistance appreciated.

Have a sql:query which runs successfully and want to save one of the fields from that query and use it in another that runs some time later, on the same page.

Attempted to save the correct row.id value (outside of the query) with -

```
String currentid ="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>
```

and then reuse in another sql:query with -

```
Select from etc etc where 
asset.id=${currentid}
```

Suspect these are basic SQL syntax errors on my part.

Regards

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get such business logic out of the JSP, i.e. into a controller in a MVC pattern, or at least into an auxiliary class called from the JSP?

Comment: I would be interested in that, too! A whole MVC pattern is a no-go. Any solution yet?